# understanding template prototype through an example of comparing two containers

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, decltype

Consider the following code:

```
// get the return type of == for T1 and T2
template<typename T1, typename T2>
using equals_op_type = decltype(std::declval<T1>() == std::declval<T2>());

template <class Container1, class Container2>
equals_op_type<typename Container1::value_type, typename Container2::value_type>
operator==(const Container1& c1, const Container2& c2) {
    if(c1.size() != c2.size()) return false;
    auto itr2 = c2.begin();
    for(const auto& v : c1) {
        cout << v << " == " << *itr2 << "? ";
        if(v != *itr2++) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is a global function intended to compare two containers.

I don't understand the function's prototype. What is `equals_op_type` exactly?

Also, what is the purpose of `equals_op_type<typename Container1::value_type, typename Container2::value_type>`?

I'd appreciate your help, since I'm new to the templates concept.

Thanks

Comment: Your question make very little sense **as the code contains a comment that explain the purpose of `equals_op_type`.** So the answer of your question is exactly the first comment in the above code: **// get the return type of == for T1 and T2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand the function's prototype. What is `equals_op_type` exactly?

Do you mean

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
using equals_op_type = decltype(std::declval<T1>() == std::declval<T2>());
```

?

It isn't a function prototipe; it defines a type (the type of the result of `T1{} == T2{}`, roughly, that should be `bool`, obviously) but **only** **if** `T1` and `T2` are comparable.

So, when you define the function

```
template <class Container1, class Container2>
equals_op_type<typename Container1::value_type, typename Container2::value_type>
operator==(const Container1& c1, const Container2& c2) {
    // function code
    return true; // or false
}
```

it becomes

```
template <class Container1, class Container2>
bool
operator==(const Container1& c1, const Container2& c2) {
    // function code
    return true; // or false
}
```

if `Container1::value_type` and `Container2::value_type` are comparable types; the substitution fail (so the operator isn't implemented but without compilation error) otherwise.

This way of operate use the rule that is synthesized with the acronym SFINAE: Substitution Failure Isn't An Error.

It plays an important role in template programming in modern c++. I suggest you of study it.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the detailed answer. It seems obvious now :)

Comment: So basically the `value_type` prevents from non-containers types getting into this function, right? (i.e. `3 == 4`)

Comment: @cppn00b - basically; if one of the passed type doesn't contain a type named `value_type` there is a substitution failure